# How to check that the stack is not corrupted

Tags: c++, gdb, stack-overflow, icc

I've got a problem with code corruption, and I need a way to check that the local stack is not messed up. I've noticed something is overwriting the `this` variable (well, that is what gdb seems to show. It displays the `this` pointer as 0x1959 or some other small 16 bit value that seems wrong), 
so I stuck in a bunch of `assert(VALID_RAM_MEMORY(this))` over the code with this definition

```
#define VALID_RAM_POINTER(x) (( (uint64_t)x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) == 0x7fff00000000ULL)
```

(All pointers in my code that addresses that look like that, ie start with 7FFF...).  However, the compiler seems to have optimized this check out. For example, if I have

```
void* a = suspicious_call();
assert(VALID_RAM_POINTER(this));
assert(VALID_RAM_POINTER(a));      //<<-- this one
assert(VALID_RAM_POINTER(this));
```

I find that the debugger (gdb) catches the assert marked "this one", and examining the value of `a` and `this`, I find that *both* `a` and `this` are bogus values like 0xabcd, instead of 0x7FFFE1484580. It seems that the compiler thinks that `this` is `const`, and so checking it multiple times is unnecessary.  I want to cast `this` as `volatile` but that's not possible (I tried). And you can't take the address of `this` (it is not an lvalue).

```
 1): warning #191: type qualifier is meaningless on cast type
              assert(VALID_MEM_POINTER((volatile decltype(this))this));
```

What can I do?  Using icc and gdb.

Comment: Have you tried using a memory analysis program like valgrind?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers - Yes, I did try valgrind but it runs so slowly, it would take approximately 80 hours to get to the point of the program where it crashes. On a short example (with smaller data set) valgrind finds no errors.

Comment: Ouch. And I thought valgrind causing something of mine to take 45 minutes was bad.

Comment: "not possible". Dubious. "I tried". Show what you tried.

Comment: @n.m. I showed what I tied to do to "cast" `this` in a volatile. You can't cast something to volatile though, that was just me grasping at straws.

Comment: Looks like `gdb` is lying to me, and all those pointers that it says are garbage are actually ok. I think `gdb` is incompatible with the `icc` compiler -- there is something screwy about the symbols or something and I'm just chasing ghosts.

Comment: Hm, it seems to work in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

One way to stop the compiler from optimizing the code away is to use a function and make sure that the function is not inline.

Declaration:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
void check_valid_ram_pointer(const void* ptr);
#else
#define check_valid_ram_pointer(x)
#endif
```

Implementation, in a .cpp file:

```
#define VALID_RAM_POINTER(x) (( (uint64_t)x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) == 0x7fff00000000ULL)

#ifdef _DEBUG
void check_valid_ram_pointer(const void* ptr)
{
   assert(VALID_RAM_POINTER(ptr));
}
#endif
```

And then use the function:

```
void* a = suspicious_call();
check_valid_ram_pointer(this);
check_valid_ram_pointer(a);
check_valid_ram_pointer(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before making suspicious call.
Get the address of first argument of the function. & last local variable of the function declared.  That is the range of stack allocated+ 2 additional address spaces for this pointer & return address. Using the debugger you can see the content of that memory range before the call & after the call. You can also find the content of this pointer, if you investigate the (+-) 2 WORDs of memory around that range.